# Angular2/4 mat-select multiple ngModel

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms, angular2-ngmodel

I have a mat-select dropdownlist with multiple enabled and am using NgModel to store user selected values.

Problem is when I navigate to another page and come back the user-selected values aren't in the mat-select..I know the ngModel has those values...I am missing something...

## HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-select placeholder="Customers" name="customerDetails" ngDefaultControl       
 formControlName="customerDetails" [(ngModel)]="custonerDetails" 
 [formControl]="customerDetailsCtrl" multiple   
 (ngModelChange)="onCustomerValueChanges(customer)" >
 
  <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customerDetailsResult"
  [value]="customer">{{customer.CustomerNo}}- 
                     {{customer.CustomerDescription}}
   </mat-option>
 </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: typo in [(ngModel)]=custonerDetails?

Comment: @MicheleSapignoli Typo when posting on here...is correct in code

Comment: See @Andrey Kolybelnikov answer below. It solves the problem.

Answer (score 12):

Depending on a use-case initializing some default options as selected might not work by simply binding to the `ngModel`, because objects in the options and in the selected subset from the previous state **have different identities**.
Thanks to the support for `compareWith` it is possible to set them as selected.

Have a look at the offical Angular docs [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#caveat-option-selection).

In Material2 demo-app they have an example of the function with two implementations. It's [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/1616f2fe90949b9ad76ac3389519fd49f3a1853c/src/demo-app/select/select-demo.html#L124).

In my component I have a collection of User objects [people] for the options of mat select. The component receives a collection of selected User objects [users] as Input from previous state. Fair enough, objects in [people] and objects in [users] have different identities and the subset in the multiple select does not initialize with selected checkboxes by default.

So, the magical `compareWith` just literally compares objects by some given values and returns true or false, and the checkboxes on the subset of [people] get the status of selected. In my code I decided to go with [(ngModel]) binding:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select [compareWith]="compareFn" name="users" [(ngModel)]="users" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let person of people" [value]="person">
           {{ person.username }}
        </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

And in the .ts file I utilize the function from the Angular doc to return true if two User objects have the same id:

```
compareFn(user1: User, user2: User) {
    return user1 && user2 ? user1.id === user2.id : user1 === user2;
}
```

If you have a similar use-case, it might work out-of-the-box.

On the what's-under-the-hood note, `compareWith` made me curious. I found out that it is based on a function in Angular2 called looseIdentical (have a look [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/a9efc48e711d77e6d49050a0ce43e847833f5575/modules/angular2/src/facade/lang.dart#L223)), which in turn derives from the identical in Dart.js library by Google. It can be found [here](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.3/dart-core/identical.html#source).

Comment: almost waste 2 hours after i find this answer it's working very nice. thanks @reddree. 1 like from me.

Comment: Saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 1):

Please check `[(ngModel)]="custonerDetails"` 
I think there is some spelling mistake and you can also use it like 
`[(value)]="custonerDetails"`.

Answer (score -2):

If you're sure that ngModel has the value in it. The issue could be that the [value] property of the mat-option is losing this selection.

Try this:

```
[ngValue]="customer" instead of [value]= "customer"
```